# Including JavaScript files from GitHub into HTML pages

Tags: javascript, github

> ## PAY ATTENTION!
>
> **You can't include Github scripts directly from Github** after [**this change**](https://github.com/blog/1482).
>
> We added the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header to our raw URL responses way back in 2011 as a first step in combating hotlinking. This has the effect of forcing the browser to treat content in accordance with the `Content-Type` header. That means that when we set `Content-Type: text/plain` for raw views of files, the browser will refuse to treat that file as JavaScript or CSS.
>
> But there are alternatives. **Check [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311329/1420197)**.

---

I am trying to include a JavaScript file from GitHub into a local HTML file for testing (like an image found on the internet: `<img src="http://...">`).

I would like something like this:

```
<script src="https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/blob/master/public/[fileName].js"></script>
```

The problem is that this doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Comment: GitHub is _not_ a CDN. If you're trying to use it as one, please don't.

Comment: `submime` text editor has awesome `Fetch` extension...pop URL in and will download any file or unpack a zip to local directory

Comment: possible duplicate of [Link and execute external JavaScript file hosted on GitHub](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

### https://rawgit.com has been shut down. This answer is unfortunately no longer relevant.

---

You will be able to do it with a URL similar to this:

```
https://rawgit.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/master/src/js/plugins.js
```

Note that this is not the same as clicking on the "raw" button within GitHub;
that button will also give you a clean version of the file, but it will be sent
with the wrong headers.

---

A Word of warning; the file is not **not being served from GitHub**. It is being
redirected through the `rawgit.com` domain. As is stated on https://rawgit.com:

> Hey! rawgit.com is just for fun and is not associated with GitHub in any
> way.

Keep in mind that the owner of that domain is now in control of the traffic and
is able to manipulate it as they see fit.

Comment: @stu - 100% correct. I've added a note in my answer to mention it.

Comment: This should not work since GitHub changed the content type for raw.github.com See https://github.com/blog/1482-heads-up-nosniff-header-support-coming-to-chrome-and-firefox ... You can use www.rawgithub.com

Comment: It seems to be serving from raw.githubusercontent.com now

Comment: Oct 8 2018 update from rawgit: "RawGit is now in a sunset phase and will soon shut down. It's been a fun five years, but all things must end."

Comment: "RawGit will soon shut down and is no longer serving new repos"

Answer (score 15):

After enabling GitHub pages of your Repository, use following link:

```
<script src="https://[username].github.io/[repository]/[filename].js"></script>
```

Comment: This works flawlessly, given that you have GitHub pages enabled...

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe it worked for you because have a `gh-pages` enabled in your repo.

Comment: @vsync Of course gh-pages must be enabled! (It is not problem, just clone public repo first, then you have full control over settings.)

Comment: what if it's the main gh pages repository?

Answer (score 7):

> rawgit looks like shutting down by end of 2019,

some options for delivering content with with proper Content-Type headers.

1. https://raw.githack.com/ , https://combinatronics.com=>exact alternative but it cannot be used for
   fetching from client side javascript, as cors is enabled here.
2. jsdelivr =>for delivering javascript files

Answer (score 6):

UPDATED ANSWER:

The old answer I gave in 2014 has stopped working, but you can use 3rd party CDN to serve js directly from github. Jsdelivr is one of those CDNs, powered by CloudFlare and Fastly.

Example:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/<user>/<repo>/<filename>.js">
```

Or use their tool to convert: https://www.jsdelivr.com/github

OLD ANSWER:

This works even with github's recent change:

```
<script>
  $.getScript("https://raw.github.com/username/repo/master/src/script.js");
</script>
```

PS. requires jQuery.

Comment: This does not send the correct headers (should be `application/json`, is `text/plain`).

Comment: @Sumit I know, that is why I'm using `getScript`, not `<script src`. Thanks for the downvote anyway.

Comment: Neither `getScript` nor `<script src` works due to the incorrect headers.

Comment: @Sumit it did in 2014

Answer (score 5):

You can include hosted **CSS**, **HTML** and **JS** file in **GITHUB PAGES**

Just click at the settings on your github repository
then at this tab scroll down to the GitHub Pages and select with the dropdown

Then HOray you can now access it live

> This is the raw that returns text/plain mime type

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bdalina54/bdalina54.github.io/master/assets/js/terebra/acrior.js

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bdalina54/bdalina54.github.io/master/assets/js/terebra/acrior.js"></script>
```

> And this is the live version

https://bdalina54.github.io/assets/js/terebra/acrior.js

```
<script src="https://bdalina54.github.io/assets/js/terebra/acrior.js"></script>
```

You can check my screenshot how I did it

https://prnt.sc/obbrpn

https://prnt.sc/obbt69

https://prnt.sc/obbskb

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/[username]/[repository]/[branch]/[filename].js"></script>
```

Here is how you can get redirected to the needed address in github:

[image]

Comment: This will *not* work since, see anser above (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14033306/167251)

Answer (score 1):

**2021 Working Solution**: Use [Combinatorics](https://combinatronics.com/).

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311271/hotlink-resources-like-javascript-files-directly-from-github/20311329#20311329) for examples. Copying here a quick one:

> The only change is from `raw.github.com` that becomes `combinatronics.com`:
>
> ```
> <script
>   type="text/javascript"
>   src="https://combinatronics.com/username/repo/master/src/file.js"
> ></script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try somethig like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/e0ne/BlogSamples/master/ModalDialog/AdvancedPopup/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

It's working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [API provided by GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68033714/9935654) to get all the context, and then use a method similar to `eval` to force write it in.

*I don't recommend you use the way in any official product, but as a test or write some practice scripts, handy, can save a lot of duplication of code*

---

[Docs GitHub API get contents](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-repository-content)

- [python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68033714/9935654)
- javascript solution (see below script `GithubExplorer`)

### Script and Example

I create a component that allows you drags the file to the input.

> [https://api.github.com/repos/**CarsonSlovoka**/**excel**/contents/**app/urls/static/js/pkg/input/ask-file.js**?ref=**d625296**](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/excel/blob/d62529601dc0e34177417cecf9d38e74c32788a7/app/urls/static/js/pkg/input/ask-file.js)

Below will show you how to load the content and embed it such that you can use it.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
<!--  Above CSS are not must be given, I want it more pretty, that all. -->

<input data-com="ask-file" placeholder="select or drag the file to attach" multiple>    

<script type="module">
  function GithubExplorer() {

    /**
     * @param {string} owner Username
     * @param {string} repo repository name
     * @param {string} path filepath
     * @param {string} branch  branch name or SHA1
     * @param {string} token The token is used for project private. generate new token  https://github.com/settings/tokens
     * */
    this.Query = async (owner, repo, path, {branch = "master", token = undefined}) => {
      // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options
      const url = `https://api.github.com/repos/${owner}/${repo}/contents/${path}?ref=${branch}`
      const headers = {
        accept: "application/vnd.github.v3.raw",
      }
      if (token) {
        headers["authorization"] = `token ${token}`
      }
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers,
      })
      if (!response.ok) {
        const errMsg = await response.text()
        throw Error(`${response.statusText} (${response.status}) | ${errMsg} `)
      }
      return await response.blob()
    }
  }

  (async () => {
    const github = new GithubExplorer()
    const blobAskFileScript = await github.Query("CarsonSlovoka", "excel", "app/urls/static/js/pkg/input/ask-file.js", {branch: "d625296"})
    let askFileScriptText = await blobAskFileScript.text()
    askFileScriptText = askFileScriptText.replaceAll("export class AskInputFile", "class AskInputFile")
    document.querySelector(`head`).append(
      document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
      <script>${askFileScriptText}<\/script>`)
    )
    AskInputFile.BuildAll() // This function is from the script.
  })()
</script>
```

---

below is a simple script that you know how to do after loading the content.

```js
const body = document.querySelector(`body`)
const range = document.createRange()
const content = `<script>console.log("hello world")<\/script>`
const frag = range.createContextualFragment(content)
body.append(frag)
```