# Cant call the function, even though its loaded.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage which has the `script` tag as :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/joelpurra/emulatetab/gh-pages/dist/emulatetab.joelpurra.min.js"></script>
```

But when I try:

```
$.emulateTab()
```

I get:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$.emulateTab()')
```

why?

I can see jquery is present, when I do `$` I get:

```
function (a, b) {return new e.fn.init(a,b,h);}
```

why I couldn't able to call `emulateTab()`?

Whats wrong here?

Comment: You are including the plugin before jQuery? Are you including multiple jQuery versions?

Comment: Yes there are multiple jQuery versions.

Comment: Then `$` doesn't refer to the jQuery version to which the plugin was attached. Check out https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1566595/218196

Comment: including the script from the github is a bad idea... download the file and host it yourself and test...

Comment: also check whether the script is properly downloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github doesn't like when people uses sources in this way, see:

> We added the X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff header to our raw URL
>   responses way back in 2011 as a first step in combating hotlinking.
>   This has the effect of forcing the browser to treat content in
>   accordance with the Content-Type header. That means that when we set
>   Content-Type: text/plain for raw views of files, the browser will
>   refuse to treat that file as JavaScript or CSS.

I think this is a reason why this plugin doesn't work in your code.

Bu you can try link to this script using http://rawgithub.com/ resource like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgithub.com/joelpurra/emulatetab/gh-pages/dist/emulatetab.joelpurra.min.js"></script>
```

Notice that I removed `.`.

More info here: [Hotlink resources like JavaScript files directly from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311271/hotlink-resources-like-javascript-files-directly-from-github/20311329#20311329)