# Cannot get cola.js to work with cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am trying to use the cola layout in a Cytoscape graph in javascript, but I get the error

```
Can not apply layout: No such layout `cola` found; did you include its JS file?
```

I have already included both the cola and cytoscape libraries as well as the adaptor required to use cola in cytoscape in my HTML:

- For cytoscape.js:
  https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola/blob/master/cytoscape-cola.js
- For cola.js: http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/cola.v3.min.js
- For cytoscape-cola.js: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cola/blob/master/cytoscape-cola.js

I don't know if there is still something else I am missing or what else I should try to include to be able to use cola!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of : [Including JavaScript files from GitHub into HTML pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033281/including-javascript-files-from-github-into-html-pages)

Use a CDN, like Unpkg or CDNJS --- or use a package manager like npm.

Comment: I have not actually included the Javascript as the raw github links. I have copied the code to local files and included local files. I just included the links to show what the .js files were that I am including.

Comment: unpkg worked! Thanks! Though I still don't understand why it shouldn't work on copying the code into local files.